# Php webscraping using simple html dom not working when output is out of order html tags

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to scrap some information of a webpage .It uses a table layout structure.

I want to extract the third table inside the nested table layout which contains a series of nested  tables .Each publishing a result .But the code is not working

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://exams.keralauniversity.ac.in/Login/index.php?reslt=1';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$result =$html->find("table", 2);
echo $result;
```

I Used Curl to extract website but the problem is its tags is in out of order so it cannot be extracted using simple dom element .

```
    function curl($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
            curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
            return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
        }

          function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
        $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
        return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
    }
          $scraped_page  = curl($url);  // Executing our curl function to scrape the webpage http://www.example.com and return the results into the $scraped_website variable

           $scraped_data = scrape_between($scraped_page, ' </html>', '</table></td><td></td></tr>
   </table>');  
 echo $scraped_data;
 $myfile = fopen("newfile.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $scraped_data);
fclose($myfile);
```

How to scrape the result and save the pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple HTML Dom can't handle that html. So first switch to [this library](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom),
Then do:

```
require_once('advanced_html_dom.php');

$dom = file_get_html('http://exams.keralauniversity.ac.in/Login/index.php?reslt=1');

$rows = array();
foreach($dom->find('tr.Function_Text_Normal:has(td[3])') as $tr){
  $row['num'] = $tr->find('td[2]', 0)->text;
  $row['text'] = $tr->find('td[3]', 0)->text;
  $row['pdf'] = $tr->find('td[3] a', 0)->href;
  if(preg_match_all('/\d+/', $tr->parent->find('u', 0)->text, $m)){
    list($row['day'], $row['month'], $row['year']) = $m[0];
  }

  // uncomment next 2 lines to save the pdf
  // $filename = preg_replace('/.*\//', '', $row['pdf']);
  // file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($row['pdf']));
  $rows[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rows);
```

Comment: have you tested it ? and little explanation

Comment: Yes I tested it. It's all css (plus jquery extensions). `td[2]` for example means the second `td`

Comment: I have upvoted it can you help me with a regular expression  to extract the published date ?

Comment: Accepted it as answer

Comment: Don't forget my bounty

Comment: I am gettting this error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a7944217/public_html/Results.php on line 477
".I have uploaded to this page http://thewebby.net16.net/Results.php **but works fine in localhost on checking using var_dump this line**  $dom->find('tr.Function_Text_Normal:has(td[3])') and **$dom  returns nullobject when dumped shows this**
object(AdvancedHtmlDom)#1 (6) { ["xpath"]=> NULL ["root"]=> NULL ["doc"]=> *RECURSION* ["dom"]=> NULL ["node"]=> NULL ["is_text"]=> bool(false) }

Answer (score 1):

```html
Find a sample code


    ?php
        // Defining the basic cURL function
        function curl($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
            curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
            return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        $scraped_website = curl("http://www.example.com");  // Executing our curl function to scrape the webpage http://www.example.com and return the results into the $scraped_website variable
$result =$substring($scraped_website ,11,7); //change values 11,7 for table
echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: I had tried curl earlier and its my fault that I did not mention it here curl successfully returns my scraped page but it cannot be parsed using simple hitml dom element because it somehow is out of shape.There is multiple body tags and there is script inside and other mess .In short I cannot scrape it even if it returns the jumbled html tags and regarding negative vote I cant unvote it until you edit it